# Error loading PKCS keystore with multiple card readers

Tags: java, smartcard, pkcs#11, smartcardio

I am running into a weird problem when reading CAC card, in a multi terminal setup, from Nth (**Except 1st**) terminal.

Environment -  JDK8_u211, Destop without any card reader, Internal card reader for laptop, USB card reader, CAC\PIV card

USE-CASE Tried

1. When the CAC card is plugged into **internal** slot of **Laptop**, everything works fine with and withou USB card terminal connected to laptop.
2. When the CAC card is plugged into the USB reader and connected to the **Desktop**, everything works fine.
3. When the CAC card is plugged into the USB reader and connected to the **Laptop**, **the PKCS store instantiation fails, as the config uses slot=1**
4. When the CAC card is plugged into the USB reader and connected to the **Laptop**, **if I hard code slot=4 in the config**, everything works fine.

Problem: Unable to determine the correct slot to use within the config file. Somehow number of terminals is not adding up to determine the slot at runtime.

By enabling JDK debug logs, i could verify that internally **"C_GetSlotList"** returns 0,4 where as I have only 2 terminals, hence using index 0 or 1.

Does anyone know how to determine the correlation between terminal vs slot or is there something really wrong in the way i am trying to read the card ?

Please advise.

Sample code

```
    public class MultipleTerminals {

    private static String DLL_PATH = "C:\\opensc-pkcs11.dll";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MyTerminal custTerminalObj = getSmartCardTerminal();
        CardTerminal terminal = custTerminalObj.getTerminal();
        Integer terminalIdx = custTerminalObj.getIndex();
        System.out.println("Using Terminal.Name: " + terminal.getName());
        System.out.println("Using Terminal.isCardPresent: " + ((CardTerminal)terminal).isCardPresent());

         if (terminal.isCardPresent()) { // duplicate check
             registerProvider(4);
             KeyStore keyStore = createKeyStore();
             printCertificate(keyStore);
         }
    }

    public static MyTerminal getSmartCardTerminal() {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        MyTerminal terminal = null;
        int terminalIdx = -1;
        try {
            TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
            if (factory != null) {
                List<CardTerminal> allTerminals = factory.terminals().list();
                for(CardTerminal term : allTerminals) {
                    System.out.println("Terminal Name: " + term.getName());
                    System.out.println("isCardPresent: " + term.isCardPresent());
                    System.out.println("----------");                   
                }
                for(CardTerminal term : allTerminals) {
                    terminalIdx++;
                    if(term.isCardPresent()) {
                        terminal = new MyTerminal();
                        terminal.setIndex(terminalIdx);
                        terminal.setTerminal(term);
                        System.out.println("Using Terminal Idx: " + terminalIdx);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (CardException e1) {
            terminal = null;
            System.out.println("SmartCardHelper.getSmartCardTerminal --> "
                    + "Exception while accessing smart-card terminal: "
                    + e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return terminal;
    }

    public static void registerProvider(Integer idx) {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        String ext = "attributes(*,*,*)=\n{\nCKA_TOKEN=true\nCKA_LOCAL=true\n}";
        String OPENSC_DEFAULT_PROVIDER_NAME = "PKCS#11";
        String OPENSC_PKCS11_DLL = DLL_PATH;
        String configString = "name = "
                + OPENSC_DEFAULT_PROVIDER_NAME.replace(' ', '_') + "\n"
                + "library = "
                + OPENSC_PKCS11_DLL + "\n slot = " + idx + " "
                + "\n attributes = compatibility \n" + ext;

        System.out.println("\tConfigString: " + configString);

        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                configString.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));

        Provider cardSecurityProvider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(
                is);

        displayProviders();
        Security.addProvider(cardSecurityProvider);
        displayProviders();
        System.out.println("==================");
    }


    public static KeyStore createKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException {
        KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection callbackHandler = new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(
                new PIVCardPinHandler());
        KeyStore.Builder builder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("PKCS11", null,
                callbackHandler);
        return builder.getKeyStore();
    }

    public static void displayProviders() {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        Provider[] objs = Security.getProviders();
        System.out.println("Provider Count: " + objs.length);

        String type = "KeyStore";
        String algorithm="PKCS11";
        ProviderList list = Providers.getProviderList();
        Provider provider = list.getProvider("SunPKCS11-PKCS");
        System.out.println("Provider[SunPKCS11-PKCS]: " + provider);

        if(provider != null) {
            Set<Service> svcs = provider.getServices();
            System.out.println("Service count: " + svcs.size());
        }

        Service firstService = list.getService(type, algorithm);
        System.out.println("Type[KeyStore], Algo[PKCS11], Service: " + firstService);       
    }

    public static void printCertificate(KeyStore keyStore)
            throws KeyStoreException {
        for (String alias : Collections.list(keyStore.aliases())) {
            System.out.println("Alias: " + alias);
        }
    }
}


class MyTerminal{

    private Integer index;
    private CardTerminal terminal;

    public MyTerminal() {
    }

    public Integer getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
    public void setIndex(Integer index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
    public CardTerminal getTerminal() {
        return terminal;
    }
    public void setTerminal(CardTerminal terminal) {
        this.terminal = terminal;
    }   
}
```

*** Output TestCase-1 (WORKING)***

```
---------------------------------------------------
Terminal Name: Alcor Micro USB Smart Card Reader 0
isCardPresent: true
----------
Terminal Name: Identive SCR33xx v2.0 USB SC Reader 0
isCardPresent: false
----------
Using Terminal Idx: 0
Using Terminal.Name: Alcor Micro USB Smart Card Reader 0
Using Terminal.isCardPresent: true
---------------------------------------------------
    ConfigString: 
name = PKCS#11
library = C:\opensc-pkcs11.dll
 slot = 0 
 attributes = compatibility 
attributes(*,*,*)=
{
CKA_TOKEN=true
CKA_LOCAL=true
}
SunPKCS11 loading ---DummyConfig-1---
sunpkcs11: Initializing PKCS#11 library C:\opensc-pkcs11.dll
Information for provider SunPKCS11-PKCS
Library info:
  cryptokiVersion: 2.20
  manufacturerID: DUMMY_VALUE                  
  flags: 0
  libraryDescription: DUMMY_VALUE      
  libraryVersion: 0.19
All slots: 0, 4
Slots with tokens: 0, 4
Slot info for slot 0:
  slotDescription: Alcor Micro USB Smart Card Reader 0                             
  manufacturerID: DUMMY_VALUE
  flags: CKF_TOKEN_PRESENT | CKF_REMOVABLE_DEVICE | CKF_HW_SLOT
  hardwareVersion: 0.00
  firmwareVersion: 0.00
Token info for token in slot 0:
  label: DUMMY_VALUE            
  manufacturerID: DUMMY_VALUE                          
  model: PKCS#15 emulated
  serialNumber: DUMMY_VALUE
  flags: CKF_RNG | CKF_LOGIN_REQUIRED | CKF_USER_PIN_INITIALIZED | CKF_TOKEN_INITIALIZED
  ulMaxSessionCount: CK_EFFECTIVELY_INFINITE
  ulSessionCount: 0
  ulMaxRwSessionCount: CK_EFFECTIVELY_INFINITE
  ulRwSessionCount: 0
  ulMaxPinLen: 8
  ulMinPinLen: 4
  ulTotalPublicMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulFreePublicMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulTotalPrivateMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulFreePrivateMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  hardwareVersion: 0.00
  firmwareVersion: 0.00
  utcTime: 
---------------------------------------------------
Provider Count: 10
Provider[SunPKCS11-PKCS]: null
Type[KeyStore], Algo[PKCS11], Service: null
---------------------------------------------------
Provider Count: 11
Provider[SunPKCS11-PKCS]: SunPKCS11-PKCS version 1.8
Service count: 26
Type[KeyStore], Algo[PKCS11], Service: SunPKCS11-PKCS: KeyStore.PKCS11 -> sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore
  aliases: [PKCS11-PKCS]
 (KeyStore)
==================
sunpkcs11: caller passed NULL pin
```

*** Output TestCase-3 (NOT WORKING)***

```
---------------------------------------------------
Terminal Name: Alcor Micro USB Smart Card Reader 0
isCardPresent: false
----------
Terminal Name: Identive SCR33xx v2.0 USB SC Reader 0
isCardPresent: true
----------
Using Terminal Idx: 1
Using Terminal.Name: Identive SCR33xx v2.0 USB SC Reader 0
Using Terminal.isCardPresent: true
---------------------------------------------------
    ConfigString: 
name = PKCS#11
library = C:\opensc-pkcs11.dll
 slot = 1 
 attributes = compatibility 
attributes(*,*,*)=
{
CKA_TOKEN=true
CKA_LOCAL=true
}
SunPKCS11 loading ---DummyConfig-1---
sunpkcs11: Initializing PKCS#11 library C:\opensc-pkcs11.dll
Information for provider SunPKCS11-PKCS
Library info:
  cryptokiVersion: 2.20
  manufacturerID: DUMMY_VALUE                  
  flags: 0
  libraryDescription: DUMMY_VALUE      
  libraryVersion: 0.19
All slots: 0, 4
Slots with tokens: 0, 4
---------------------------------------------------
Provider Count: 10
Provider[SunPKCS11-PKCS]: null
Type[KeyStore], Algo[PKCS11], Service: null
---------------------------------------------------
Provider Count: 11
Provider[SunPKCS11-PKCS]: SunPKCS11-PKCS version 1.8
Service count: 0
Type[KeyStore], Algo[PKCS11], Service: null
==================
Exception in thread "main" java.security.KeyStoreException: KeyStore instantiation failed
    at java.security.KeyStore$Builder$2.getKeyStore(KeyStore.java:1967)

Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:851)
    at java.security.KeyStore$Builder$2$1.run(KeyStore.java:1923)
    at java.security.KeyStore$Builder$2$1.run(KeyStore.java:1918)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.KeyStore$Builder$2.getKeyStore(KeyStore.java:1964)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PKCS11 KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)
    ... 6 more
```

*** Output TestCase-4 (WORKING)***

```
---------------------------------------------------
Terminal Name: Alcor Micro USB Smart Card Reader 0
isCardPresent: false
----------
Terminal Name: Identive SCR33xx v2.0 USB SC Reader 0
isCardPresent: true
----------
Using Terminal Idx: 1
Using Terminal.Name: Identive SCR33xx v2.0 USB SC Reader 0
Using Terminal.isCardPresent: true
---------------------------------------------------
    ConfigString: 
name = PKCS#11
library = C:\opensc-pkcs11.dll
 slot = 4 
 attributes = compatibility 
attributes(*,*,*)=
{
CKA_TOKEN=true
CKA_LOCAL=true
}
SunPKCS11 loading ---DummyConfig-1---
sunpkcs11: Initializing PKCS#11 library C:\opensc-pkcs11.dll
Information for provider SunPKCS11-PKCS
Library info:
  cryptokiVersion: DUMMY_VALUE
  manufacturerID: DUMMY_VALUE                  
  flags: 0
  libraryDescription: DUMMY_VALUE      
  libraryVersion: DUMMY_VALUE
All slots: 0, 4
Slots with tokens: 0, 4
Slot info for slot 4:
  slotDescription: DUMMY_VALUE                           
  manufacturerID: DUMMY_VALUE
  flags: CKF_TOKEN_PRESENT | CKF_REMOVABLE_DEVICE | CKF_HW_SLOT
  hardwareVersion: 0.00
  firmwareVersion: 0.00
Token info for token in slot 4:
  label: DUMMY_LABEL            
  manufacturerID: DUMMY_VALUE                          
  model: PKCS#15 emulated
  serialNumber: DUMMY_VALUE
  flags: CKF_RNG | CKF_LOGIN_REQUIRED | CKF_USER_PIN_INITIALIZED | CKF_TOKEN_INITIALIZED
  ulMaxSessionCount: CK_EFFECTIVELY_INFINITE
  ulSessionCount: 0
  ulMaxRwSessionCount: CK_EFFECTIVELY_INFINITE
  ulRwSessionCount: 0
  ulMaxPinLen: 8
  ulMinPinLen: 4
  ulTotalPublicMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulFreePublicMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulTotalPrivateMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulFreePrivateMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  hardwareVersion: 0.00
  firmwareVersion: 0.00
  utcTime: 
---------------------------------------------------
Provider Count: 10
Provider[SunPKCS11-PKCS]: null
Type[KeyStore], Algo[PKCS11], Service: null
---------------------------------------------------
Provider Count: 11
Provider[SunPKCS11-PKCS]: SunPKCS11-PKCS version 1.8
Service count: 26
Type[KeyStore], Algo[PKCS11], Service: SunPKCS11-PKCS: KeyStore.PKCS11 -> sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore
  aliases: [PKCS11-PKCS]
 (KeyStore)
==================
sunpkcs11: caller passed NULL pin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting confused between **slot id** and **slot index**. They are two different attributes.

The `C_GetSlotList` gives you an array of `slot id's` not slot indexes. In your case `0` and `4` are slot id's, not slot indexes. The slot index is the index of the slot id in the array.

In your `getSmartCardTerminal()` method where you are identifying the `terminalIdx` you are identifying the index, but in your `registerProvider(Integer idx)` method you are mapping the index as the id, here:

> OPENSC_PKCS11_DLL + "\n **slot** = " + idx + " "

When you are using the slot index you should be using `slotListIndex` and when you are using the slot id, you should be using `slot`.

So to fix your problem change it to:

> OPENSC_PKCS11_DLL + "\n **slotListIndex** = " + idx + " "

Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html).

Comment: After making changes recommended by "always_a_rookie_to_learn" everything worked.

Comment: Now that I have update OpenSC version from 19 to 20, I get to see PKCS initialization errors due to index... based on the PKCS logs appears to be DLL issue fixed in v20                All slots: 0, 4
Slots with tokens: 4
Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
at registerProvider(MultipleTerminals.java:115)
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: slotListIndex is 1 but token only has 1 slots at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:357)